# Issue with MUI DateCalendar: Year not updating when changing year via months selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, calendar

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm facing an issue with the MUI (Material-UI) DateCalendar component in my project. When I open the year selector and then try to change the year using the months selector, I'm noticing that the year in the year selector doesn't update accordingly.

I think this behaviour is also present on the official documentation of MUI.(check below video)

[image]

I need to change the year in year selector also when we change the months to differnet year.

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/date-calendar-stackoverflow-demo-pgm8yg)

Any help, insights, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Please include code. This is near impossible to debug. If I was to guess I'd say that you're probably using `useState` incorrectly and not triggering the new state update through `onChange` in the MUI calendar component.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added a code sandbox link in the description, I hope this will be helpful. @JoeMoore